# Does HQL have an equivalent for Restrictions.ilike (for case-insensitive matching)?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, derby

I wrote a project for Hibernate+MySQL. Now I'm porting it to Derby (for a number of reasons).

Now I discovered that Derby is case sensitive when using LIKE in queries. This could be solved using [`Restrictions.ilike(...)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#ilike%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) in Criteria queries... but I've many *complex* HQL queries that use that. Is there a way to have a functionality similar to `ilike` in HQL?

Comment: You are telling **like** will not work HQL in Derby database?

Comment: like *will* work, but case sensitive

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no `ilike` equivalent functionality in HQL. As Konstantin has already pointed out in his [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977765/hql-like-and-case-sensitive/7977958#7977958), your best choice is to [tune the database connection](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefattrib24612.html) and set [collation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefattribcollation.html) to `TERRITORY_BASED:SECONDARY`, as explained in this JIRA: [DERBY-1748: Global case insensitive setting](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-1748).

Take into account that all equalities (`=`) and `like`s will be case insensitive. This might go a bit too far, and be not suitable for your particular situation.

Another way of addressing this would be creating function-based indexes (if Derby supports them, of course) and tune your HQL to combine `like` and `lower` like this.

```
Query q = session.createQuery("... WHERE lower(entity.field) like lower(?)");
q.setString(0, '%' + variable + '%');
```

If Derby doesn't support FBI's (I think it doesn't), you could also create trigger-filled columns with the lower values and index them.

**UPDATE** It seems to be possible to define derived/autogenerated columns, as explained in this other JIRA: [JIRA-481: implement SQL generated columns](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-481).

Comment: but gotch4 prefers to keep his HQL queries

Comment: He has no other option if he doesn't want to change the connection collation. And I understood he doesn't want to turn them into criteria queries.

Comment: I understand him - could be hell of a refactoring and testing

Comment: I started the troublesome work of converting everything to Criteria... this way I hope I will avoid this in the future.

Comment: It's alright. Just take into account that using `ilike` will be the same as modifying the HQL with `WHERE lower(entity.field) LIKE ?` and applying `toLowerCase()` to the parameter. If those `entity.field` were indexed you can run into performance issues.

Comment: if you like, you can use "lower(entity.field) like lower(?)" too, if you wish to let DB to process the String lower case. In my case I prefer this way to let the statement easier to read...

Comment: There's a subtle bug lurking in the example code here: There is no guarantee that the JDK's String#toLowerCase() will actually always produce the same result as the "lower()" function on the database server. So unless you want spent hours debugging (and yes, this has happened to me), I suggest to always do the conversion on the DB-side.

Comment: @TobiasGierke That is a very valid point. I have updated the answer to squash that out. As long as DB-side `lower('%')` is guaranteed to remain the same :) Concatenating `'%' || lower(?) || '%'` in the query itself probably a safer move, but not sure right now how would that play out if possible at all in a HQL query.

Answer (score 2):

I'm affraid, there is no way to achieve this via HQL, as it is just translated to native  SQL.  I think it could be possible by tuning schema:

http://old.nabble.com/case-insensitive-searching-td17756019.html

Answer (score 0):

a easy workaround would be to convert both words to to upper case (or lower case)  something like this:

from DomesticCat cat where upper(cat.name) like 'FRI%'

references: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html